# How to solve --Ignored (for causing prior/excessive GPU errors) (IOAF code 4)

Tags: ios, swift

How to solve this Execution:

My project use ARVideoKit https://github.com/AFathi/ARVideoKit
Press the phone's home button to exit the app, the following exception will occur

> Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during
>   execution. Ignored (for causing prior/excessive GPU errors) (IOAF code
>   4)

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you need to give more details.